# Sitecore Stimulsoft Reports Add Two Date Range Selectors

Tags: sitecore, stimulsoft

I am creating some reports using Sitecore stimulsoft report designer 20009.3.600. Is it possible to add another date range selector in addition to the one already there ?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the reports and the filters/ parameters.

Checkout the [report designer cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/report_designer_cookbook_sc65-a4.pdf) for details

There is some additional information [here](http://admin.stimulsoft.com/Documentation/Online/index.html?data_data_dictionary_variables_request_from_user.htm) on variables for the reports.